# How to switch tags via awesome API

Tags: awesome

I've been digging around in the API documentation, and I'm having limited sucess
switching tags from within awesome-client.  Basically, I can switch tags with:

```
awful.tag.viewidx(2)
```

But that is relative not absolute.  From looking in my rc.lua, looks like what
I need is:

```
local screen = mouse.screen
awful.tag.viewonly(tags[screen][2])
```

But I get the following error instead:

```
attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
```

What is the most concise way of changing tags (preferably one command) to an absolute tag number.  Alternatively, how can I find the current tag?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error this is what I came up with:

```
awful.tag.viewonly(tags[1][3])
```

This will switch to the third tag.

Comment: Only on the first screen, even if the focus is on the second screen.

Comment: The first argument to `tags` is the screen number.